# Is it possible to replace a specific layer(s) in a ZIO effect and keep the rest of the environment?

Tags: scala, zio

ChatGPT says this should work, but looks like it is mistaken :/

```
      trait Foo { def s: String }
      case object A extends Foo { def s = "A" }
      case object B extends Foo { def s = "B" }
      test("Replace a service in ZIO") {
        val layer = ZLayer.succeed[Foo](A)
        val otherLayer = ZLayer.succeed[Foo](B)
        val app = (for {
          foo <- ZIO.service[Foo]
          bar <- ZIO.service[String]
        } yield foo.s + bar).provide(layer, ZLayer.succeed("foo"))

        val otherApp = app.provideSomeLayer(otherLayer)
        otherApp.map { s => assertTrue(s == "Bfoo") }
      }
```

I have an `app` here that has service A and string "foo". Trying to create the `otherApp` from it, replacing A with B, and keeping the rest ("foo") as is.
But no luck - this test fails because the resulting value is still "Afoo" rather than "Bfoo".

What am I doing wrong?

Also (on a sort of different topic), if I change `provide` there to
`provideLayer(layer).provide(ZLayer.succeed("foo")`, it no longer compiles saying it wants `layer` to be `Foo with String`. Is there no way to provide *some* dependencies to the effect, and leave others undefined?

And one more noob question, while I have your attention. At which point do these ZIOs actually *run*? Does this test run them both? Or will it only run the `otherApp` because it is the only one that is used to produce the return value?

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to create the `otherApp` from it, replacing `A` with `B`, and keeping the rest (`"foo"`) as is.

I don't *think* you can "replace" a layer once it's been provided.

I'm actually even surprised that your usage of `provideSomeLayer` doesn't raise an error because you provided too much layers. Usually it fails to compile when a unnecessary layer is provided.

---

> Is there no way to provide some dependencies to the effect, and leave others undefined?

Yes, `provideSome` will do it:

```scala
val program: ZIO[Foo with String, Nothing, String] = (for {
  foo <- ZIO.service[Foo]
  bar <- ZIO.service[String]
} yield foo.s + bar)

// Providing only the String type, and leaving Foo to be defined later
val appPartial: ZIO[Foo, Nothing, String] = program.provideSome[Foo](ZLayer.succeed("foo"))

// Defining Foo now with B
val otherApp: ZIO[Any, Nothing, String] = appPartial.provide(otherLayer)
```

---

> At which point do these ZIOs actually run?

If you were outside a ZIO test, nothing would run until you give the `ZIO` to a ["runtime"](https://zio.dev/reference/core/runtime/) with something like this:

```scala
Unsafe.unsafe { implicit unsafe =>
  zio.Runtime.default.unsafe.run(otherApp).getOrThrowFiberFailure()
}
```

**But** in a ZIO test context, the framework runs the effects for you. So you don't need this "runtime" thing. And I *assume* that it only runs the effect of the returned value.

Comment: Hm ... so, to be able to mock services in a large environment, it looks like you have to pre-assembled versions of that environment for every possible combination? 
Like `envWithoutDatabaseX`, `envWithoutDatabaseY`, `envWithoutXorY`  ... 
That's ... inconvenient. But _moreover_ it looks like `provideSome` wants me to enumerate all the dependencies I am _not_ providing explicitly. I think, I  must be just using it wrong somehow ... can't believe I am the first onne who stumbled upon this :/ 
I

Comment: Not sure I fully get what you're experiencing. In the tests I write, I always give the complete list of dependencies (not using `provideSome` at all) and the list of dependencies is constructed from a combination of live services and mocked ones depending on the test. What do you expect in terms of developer experience? (Might be easier to transform this into a discussion on Discord I guess).

Comment: I see what you mean ... That works for "true" unit tests when you are focusing on testing a single component with, perhaps, a handful of dependencies. I was thinking about a use case, which is more akin to a "functional test" - fork the entire service, and send requests to it ... But I guess, it can be said that for that kind of test, one shouldn't be mocking anything in the first place. In the ideal world, that would work. But having to start a dozen of docker containers with various mock databases etc. just to run a test ... sucks :(

Comment: I do it for functional tests, loading the whole program as well. It can be a bit painful to wire all dependencies and mocks, indeed. But still I don't see how that would be different in another framework with Guice or similar.